# How do I set an array to a new array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to implement a function that modifies an array. The new array may be a different size. `cout` prints 1. I understand what's wrong with this code but I just cannot figure out what the syntax is.

```
//tried this..
int reduce(int *array[])
{
    *array = new int[1];
    (*array)[0] = 6;
    return 0;
}

//also tried this..
int reduce(int array[])
{
    array = new int [1];
    array[0] = 6;
    return 0;
}    

int main()
{
    int a[1] = {1};
    int *p = a;

    reduce(&p);
    cout << a[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between local array and dynamically allocated array?

Comment: @Marcusw1 You are allocating a new array inside the function call. It will remove the previous reference and add a new reference.

Comment: Yes, but the point of my function is to take an array , and modify it based on the data. The modified new array will have a smaller size.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` instead, passing it by reference to anything you want to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand your question correctly, but this is what you may do:

```
void reduce(int *a, int size)
{
    for (int i =0; i < size; ++i) {
        *(a+i) = 6; // or whatever value to want to
    }
}
```

Call it this way:

```
int main(){
    int a[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int *p = a;

    reduce(p, 5);
    for (int i =0; i < 5; ++i) { cout << a[i]<<endl; }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

What you are trying to do can be vaguely done this way:

```
int * reduce (int **b, int size) {
    *b = new int[size];
    for (int i =0; i < size; ++i) {
        *(*b + i) = 6;
    }
    return *b;
}


int main(){
    int a[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int *p = a;

    p = reduce(&p, 5);
    cout << p[0];
    cout << p[1];
    cout << p[2];
    cout << p[3];
    cout << p[4];

    delete [] p;

    return 0;
}
```

But it still wont change where `a` is pointing to.

Comment: @Marcusw1 But after the function call the new array will be destroyed as it is not a global variable but a function variable. So, it will not update in the main function as your are removing the reference.

Comment: okay i guess the ONLY way is to return new array then ? 

the assignment is not clear on return value.

Answer (score 0):

MODIFIED:

You want to modify array a, try this :

```
int reduce(int **array)
{
    *array = new int[1];
    (*array)[0] = 6;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int *a = new int[1];
    reduce(&a);
    cout << a[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im not trying to only modify data. AFTER THE FUNCTION the NEW array may be LARGER or a it may be SMALLER

Comment: @Marcusw1Code is modified. You want to modify what a points, so make it on the heap.

Comment: As a bonus, you can quickly and proficiently leak memory this way as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes , the answer does not consider the leak memory problem. And the right way is using `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible with statically defined arrays.

When you use an array like

```
int a[1] = {1};
```

you cannot change the size of the array at run time, you cannot make it point to dynamically allocated memory. You may only access and modify the elements the array. That's it.

The function `reduce` changes where `p` points to but it does not change the elements of `a`.

If you want to modify the contents of `a`, you can simply use `a` as an argument, and set the values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the formal parameter `int* array[]` actually is the same as `int** array` (you can think of it as a two-dimensional array). This is probably not what you want.

The answer of @everettjf will only work if you do **not** change the size of the array. A possible solution (that completely replaces the array) would be

```
#include <iostream>
void print_array(int[],int);

int* reduce(int array[]) {
    // get rid of the old array
    delete[] array;

    // create a new one
    array = new int[7]{8,4,6,19,3,56,23};

    // need to return the new address, so that
    // the main function is informed on the new
    // address
    return array;
}

int main() {
    // initialize array
    int *a = new int[1]{4};

    print_array(a,1);

    // "change" array by completely replacing it
    a=reduce(a);

    print_array(a,7);

    return 0;
}

// simply prints out the array; no error checking!
void print_array(int array[], int length) {
    std::cout << "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < length ; ++i) {
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

In the `reduce` function, the initial array is completely deleted. Afterwards, you can create a new one (I chose to just use 7 random numbers). It is important to return that pointer back to the caller (the `main` method). Otherwise the `a` pointer in the main method would point to invalid

If you are not forced (by some kind of excercise, for example) to use arrays, you should look into [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector%22std::vector%3E)

Answer (score 0):

The premise of your question is invalid.   It is not possible to resize an array of automatic storage duration (aka `a` in `main()`) after its definition by ANY means in standard C++.

Dynamic memory allocations in either of your `reduce()` functions  will not cause `a` in `main()` to be resized.

`reduce(&p)` will calls the first version of `reduce()` , which will then change `p` (so it points at the dynamically allocated memory) but not affect `a`.

If `main()` calls `reduce(a)` or `reduce(p)` (the two are equivalent, given the initialisation `int *p = a`) will change neither `a` nor `p`, but instead cause a memory leak.

The underlying problem, I suspect, is that you believe - incorrectly - that pointers and arrays are the same thing.  They are actually different things, but can be used in the same way in various contexts.  And your code is one of the contexts in which they cannot be used interchangeably.

If you want a resizeable array, use a static container (like `std::vector<int>`) and - if you want a function to resize it, pass it by reference.    It manages its own memory dynamically, so is able to dynamically resize itself.

Comment: well its a hw assignment. I didnt think it was possible but thats because i am not proficient in c++, therefore i thought i should ask here.